# Drop or create database from stored procedure in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql, ddl, dblink

I have a function that looks like this:

```
BEGIN
  DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS db_1;
END;
```

I'm getting the following error:

> ERROR: DROP DATABASE cannot be executed from a function or multi-command string.

Is it not possible to drop a database from a stored procedure in PostgreSQL? I'm using plpgsql.

Comment: You can do it from another database

Comment: You can try to `dblink` to any db on this cluster (exept the one you want to drop) and execute `DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS db_1;` from `dblink`.

Comment: I believe the error message is quite clear.

Answer (score 4):

The error message is just a s clear as [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-dropdatabase.html) on this:

> `DROP DATABASE` cannot be executed inside a transaction block.

A plgpsql function is surrounded by a transaction block automatically. The long and the short of it: you cannot do that - directly. Is there a particular reason you can't just call the DDL command?

```
DROP database $mydb;
```

You *can* circumvent these restrictions with the additional module [**dblink**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/dblink.html) as [@Igor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15256793/drop-or-create-database-from-stored-procedure-in-postgresql#comment21522666_15256793) suggested. You need to install it once per database - the one where you call dblink functions, not the (other) one you execute commands in.
Allows you to write a function using [`dblink_exec()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/contrib-dblink-exec.html) like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_drop_db(text)
  RETURNS text LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
SELECT dblink_exec('port=5432 dbname=postgres'
                  ,'DROP DATABASE ' || quote_ident($1))
$func$;
```

`quote_ident()` prevents possible SQL injection.

Call:

```
SELECT f_drop_db('mydb');
```

On success you see:

> DROP DATABASE

The connection string could even point to the same db your session runs in. The command runs outside a transaction block, which has two consequences:

- It cannot be rolled back.
- It allows you to call `DROP DATABASE` "by way of a proxy" from within a function.

You could create a `FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER` and a `FOREIGN SERVER` to store a connection and simplify the call:

```
CREATE FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgresql VALIDATOR postgresql_fdw_validator;

CREATE SERVER your_fdw_name_here FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgresql
OPTIONS (hostaddr '12.34.56.78', port '5432', dbname 'postgres');
```

Using default maintenance db `postgres`, which would be obvious choice. But any db is possible.

Simplified function making use of that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_drop_db(text)
  RETURNS text LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
SELECT dblink_exec('your_fdw_name_here', 'DROP DATABASE ' || quote_ident($1))
$func$;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't do it from a procedure, because the `drop database` can't be executed inside a  transaction, and a stored procedure is considered as a transaction itself. (See [reference](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-dropdatabase.html))

What about the [dropdb](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-dropdb.html) ?

Comment: I am doing from another db. The sp is in db_2 and I'm running it from there. I'll try from postgres

Comment: This is obviously not the primary problem here. Have you read the error message?