# Updating database rows without locking the table in PostgreSQL 9.2

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, database-cursor

Trying to run an update statement like this on a table, using PostgreSQL 9.2:

```
UPDATE table
    SET a_col = array[col];
```

We need to be able to run this on a ~10M row table, and not have it lock up the table (so normal operations can still happen while the update is running).  I believe using a cursor will probably be the right solution, but I really have no idea if it is or how I should implement it using a cursor.

I have come up with this cursor code, which I think might be good.

**Edit: Added cursor function**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_fields() RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE
        cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id FOR UPDATE;
BEGIN
        FOR row IN cursor LOOP
                UPDATE table SET
                        a_col = array[col],
                        a_col2= array[col2]
                WHERE CURRENT OF cursor;
        END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Are there any other object referencing that table, like foreign keys of views?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Nope, no foreign keys at all.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### MVCC

First off, if "normal operations" consist of `SELECT` queries, the [MVCC model](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/mvcc-intro.html) will take care of it automatically. `UPDATE` does not block `SELECT` and vice versa. `SELECT` only sees committed data (or what's been done in the same transaction), so the result of the big `UPDATE` remains invisible to other transactions until it's done (committed).

#### Performance / bloat

*If* you don't have other objects referencing that table,
*and* you don't have concurrent write operations (which would be lost!),
*and* you can afford a very short exclusive lock on the table,
*and* you have the additional disk space, of course:
You could keep the locking to a minimum by creating an updated version of the table in the background. Make sure it has *everything* to be a drop-in replacement, then drop the original and rename the dupe.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_new (LIKE tbl_org INCLUDING CONSTRAINTS);

INSERT INTO tbl_new 
SELECT col_a, col_b, array[col] aS col_c
FROM   tbl_org;
```

I am using `CREATE TABLE (LIKE .. INCLUDING CONSTRAINTS)`, because ([quoting the manual here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtable.html)):

> Not-null constraints are always copied to the new table. `CHECK`
>   constraints will only be copied if `INCLUDING CONSTRAINTS` is specified;
>   other types of constraints will never be copied.

Make sure, the new table is ready. Then:

```
DROP tbl_org;
ALTER TABLE tbl_new RENAME TO tbl_org;
```

Results in an very short time window, where the table is locked exclusively.

This is really only about performance. It creates a new table without any bloat rather quickly. If you have foreign keys or views, you can still go that route, but you have to prepare a script to drop and recreate these objects, potentially creating additional exclusive locks.

#### Concurrent writes

With concurrent write operations, really all you can do, is split your update in chunks. You can't do that in a single transaction, since locks are only released at the end of a transaction.

You *could* employ [**dblink**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/dblink.html), which can launch independent transactions on another database, including itself. This way you could do it all in a single `DO` statement or a plpgsql function with a loop. Here is a loosely related answer with more information on dblink:

- [Drop or create database from stored procedure in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15256793/drop-or-create-database-from-stored-procedure-in-postgresql/15260931#15260931)

#### Your approach with cursors

A cursor inside the function will not buy you *anything*. Any function is enclosed in a transaction automatically, and all locks are only released at the end of the transaction. 
Even if you used [`CLOSE cursor`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-cursors.html#AEN57057) (which you don't) it would only free some resources, but *not* release acquired locks on the table. I quote the manual:

> `CLOSE` closes the portal underlying an open cursor. This can be used to
>   release resources earlier than end of transaction, or to free up the
>   cursor variable to be opened again.

You would need to run ***separate* transactions** or (ab)use [dblink](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/dblink.html) which does that for you.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer.  "Normal operations" includes update statements as well.  I was thinking of using a cursor (please see my updated question) to do this, but I'm not sure if that's a good idea.

Comment: @JuanCarlosCoto: I am afraid, cursors are not a good idea. I added a bit to my answer.